# Zip list of tuples with flat list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do the following in Python 3.x. Say I have two lists structured as follows:

```
list_a = [(1,2), (1,2), (1,2), ...]
list_b = [3, 3, 3, ...]
```

What's the simplest way to produce a generator (here represented by calling a function `funky_zip`) that would let me iterate through these two lists like so:

```
>>> for a, b, c, in funky_zip(list_a, list_b):
>>>      print(a, b, c)
...
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
# and so on
```

I could just do

```
for aa, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    print(aa[0], aa[1], b)
```

but I'm wondering if there's a nice way to do this without having to unpack the tuples. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need parentheses:

```
list_a = [(1,2), (1,2), (1,2)]
list_b = [3, 3, 3]
for (a, b), c in zip(list_a, list_b):
    print(a, b, c)
```

Result:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Comment: OMG haha. Didn't know Python could do that! Thanks